# Series, sum uniform convergence

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, uniform-convergence, implicit-function-theorem

Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(e^{\frac{x}{n}}-1-\frac{x}{n})$ converges uniformly in $\left[-A,A\right]$ for any $A>0$.Show also that the sum of the series is a function with derivatives of all orders in $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to use the Weierstrass M test, by trying $sup_{x\in \left[-A,A\right]}(e^{\frac{x}{n}}-1-\frac{x}{n})=e^{\frac{A}{n}}-1-\frac{A}{n}$, but could not prove the convergence then.

Comment: $e^{\frac{A}{n}}-1-\frac{A}{n}=O(\frac 1 {n^{2}})$.

Comment: If you cannot use @geetha290krm hint, you could use the Lagrange error bound to find a suitable bound for this series of functions.